# Interoperability of Three Application

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

Now I'm faced with the problem of interoperability among three separate systems. There are three machines running the different applications. Application A use MsSQL Server 2008, application B use Oracle Database Server, and application C use MySQL.

To generate some monthly reports, application A must retrieves data automatically from the databases of application B and C. The data that retrieve is not too large, query result max is 100 rows. But The data is confidential and should not be spread to the public. So the data security aspect must be considered as an important thing.For some reason, changes or additions to the code on each application A, B, and C are not allowed. Only data access is allowed.

After doing a little research, I came up with the following basic idea as a solution:

1. Create a webservice as application communication bridge
2. Create a webservice client for each application. So for Application A,  there will be a webservice client application: Ws-A-Client. For B: Ws-B-Client. And C: Ws-C-Client. Generally, Ws-B-Client take the data from Database B and  do request to Webservice to store data into the Webservice database. WS-C-Client do the similiar thing as WS-B-Client, take data from Database C and store it into Webservice database. WS-A-Client perform automatically data request to webservice and store it in Database A.

Then I tried to implement the idea using php NuSoap Library and create SOAP Client and Server. But now, I'm in doubt whether the idea is the right solution for this problem. Because, it becomes more complicated due to the need for data synchronization on the system.

There is no web server installed on A, B, and C. So that there is no direct SOAP communication between applications A, B, and C. All data from A, B, and C will be stored in a separate web service database. So if application need something from the a client, they will contact the web service to provide the data. The reason I did it because i think  If the data stored in the single database ( in the Webservice ), it will facilitate the use of this data for other purposes. For example, it is possible to use these data to be displayed as management information, without the need to request to each applications. Or For instance, the data can be extracted or processed and display it in organization website. So that, I decided, I do not need to install the web service on each machine (A, B, or C). Each machines only has a php script program that only serves to make the SOAP request (just as SOAP client), but
can not perform as a SOAP Server. The SOAP sever only exist on separate Webservice. But I'm not sure wheather it's an proper way or not...

Here's the problem case. Suppose a user on the application B change the data which had been sent to the webservice before. As a result WS-Client-B must be able to detect the changes made by this user, and perform request to webservice to update related data on webservice database. Furthermore, if the data has been retrieved by the application A and stored in its database, then the data in the database A also needs to be updated. So, it became more complicated.

My question is:
Can you give me advice about the proper way or step to solve this problem. Is it appropriate to use webservice in this case,or is there any other simpler way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why to store the data? As you said that data is not too large then read the data when you have to generate report.

Comment: It sounds like all your applications (at least A and B) should always have a real time copy of the other application's data? I actually agree with Garry, why do you have to store the data when you can just fetch it on the fly right when you need a report?

Comment: To answer your question, i've edit my post. Because it's too long to explain here in the comment box. Thanks for your respond..

Comment: @gery, tworabbits: No, all the data stored in a separate webservice database. If A need data from B, A will request to web service. So that, B and C must have a mechanism to request webservice to insert, update, or delete their data.